# Expected all tensors to be on the same device, PyTorch Lightning

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I try to implement neural machine translition model using PyTorch Lightning (also known as pl) for training process. While we use pl, we can't use .to('cuda') or .cuda() functions for tensors. When I train my model without pl, the whole process went fine, but after using pl I have this error (use 2 gpu in kaggle):

```
Cell In[70], line 21, in EncoderTransformerLayer.forward(self, value, key, query, mask)
     18 def forward(self, value, key, query, mask):
     19     # attn_output = self.dropout(self.norm(self.attention(value, key, query, mask))) 
     20     # mlp_output = self.dropout(self.norm(self.mlp(attn_output))) # сюда pre ln
---> 21     value = self.norm_for_v(value)
     22     key = self.norm_for_k(key)
     23     query = self.norm_for_q(query)

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument weight in method wrapper_CUDA__native_layer_norm)
```

The output shows that the error is in this piece of code:

```
class EncoderTransformerLayer(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim: int, num_heads: int, dropout: float = 0.1):
        super().__init__()

        self.attention = AttentionModule(hidden_dim, num_heads)
        self.mlp = MLP(hidden_dim)

        # self.norm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(hidden_dim)
        # self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.norm_for_v = torch.nn.LayerNorm(hidden_dim)
        self.norm_for_k = torch.nn.LayerNorm(hidden_dim)
        self.norm_for_q = torch.nn.LayerNorm(hidden_dim)

        self.norm_for_attention = torch.nn.LayerNorm(hidden_dim)
        self.norm_for_mlp = torch.nn.LayerNorm(hidden_dim)

    def forward(self, value, key, query, mask):
        # attn_output = self.dropout(self.norm(self.attention(value, key, query, mask))) 
        # mlp_output = self.dropout(self.norm(self.mlp(attn_output))) # сюда pre ln
        value = self.norm_for_v(value)
        key = self.norm_for_k(key)
        query = self.norm_for_q(query)

        attn_output = self.attention(value, key, query, mask)
        attn_output = self.norm_for_attention(attn_output)

        mlp_output = self.mlp(attn_output)
        mlp_output = self.norm_for_mlp(mlp_output)

        return mlp_output
```

What should I change in the code to make it work?

I try use .cpu() for these tensors (yeah, it's a foolish decision), but it didnt'work. After this attempt I haven't any idea for debugging -((